# Dell Precision 3520 keyboard backlight timeout

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision 3520 laptop, which has a backlit keyboard. There's a function key to turn it off and change the brightness between 1 of 2 values. The backlight starts to fade out after 10 seconds of inactivity, and after 2 or 3 seconds is then unlit. Is there a tool or method to increase the timeout, or turn the timeout off altogether?

`Dell Feature Enhancement Pack` is not compatible with this device, and there's nothing under Windows Mobility options which was also suggested on a Dell forum.

Comment: have you checked the bios menu?

Comment: No, it's a corporate machine so I don't have access to the BIOS.

Comment: i mentioned this because i have an HP laptop with a keyboard backlight and the timeout settings are in the bios, I don't know if dell is the same but it may also be so i guess you are out of luck?

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can gain access via our ICT team. Thanks for the tip.